# Is there any WWW-Authenticate header that will prompt user for only password?

Tags: http, basic-authentication

I'm developing a scheme where a password alone (not username) grants access to documents.  WWW-Authenticate: Basic will prompt user for both username and password.  Is there any way to direct standard browsers to just display the password field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't have only a password field. 
However, you can allow an empty username (or any random username), and use your REALM text to inform your users.